# How to treat a class a sub-class when it do not want to have all the methods declared at its superclass?

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism

What if I want to treat `ToyTruck` as a subclass of `Truck` but I don't want to have all the methods declared in the `Truck` class?. For example, the `Truck` class has a method `addGasoline()` but the a `ToyTruck` do not need gasoline to work. One solution I get is that I will just override the `addGasoline()` method and implement it as an empty method. But for me, this not make the `ToyTruck` to not have a method `addGasoline()`. And one more solution I think is do this as a composition, but I don't know where to start and how will I use polymorphism using composition.

Comment: This is the common issue solved by abiding the [liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). "*If it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, but needs batteries - You probably have the wrong abstraction.*"

Comment: Cannot imagine a business domain where toy and real trucks are mixed. And how to deal with diesel trucks and electrically powered ones?..

Answer (score 2):

In this case, ToyTruck is not a Truck, and probably shouldn't be a subclass. Instead, consider making a set of interfaces that describe your truck. For example `Moveable` etc.

You could also make Truck abstract, and have a third class called `LargeTruck` which represents an actual truck.

If this is not an option, you could consider overriding `addGasoline()` in ToyTruck and making it throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`, however this does not prevent the method from being called, it simply makes it fail sooner.

Just consider whether it really makes sense for ToyTruck to be a subclass of `Truck`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I will just try your first suggestion